# How to make a phone vibrate with sancha-touch?(Android)

Tags: android, sencha-touch

I use  Sancha-touch + PhoneGap to create my application and test it on a phone (Android2.1).

Does someone know the code to make the phone vibrate (still using Sencha-touch)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the PhoneGap documentation: [PhoneGap API Doc: Notification](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html)

Comment: The problem is that i not sure i cant use that while i am working with sencha touch. I can't write: navigator.notification.vibrate(); in my functions in sencha touch.

Comment: This is the only way and I don't know why you shouldn't be able to write `navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);` Works fine in my app :)

Comment: ok indeed it has nothing  to do with sencha touch sorry. it seems to be  navigator.notification.vibrate(1000); but  it s not working for me. the error is :Cannot call method 'vibrate' of undefined

Comment: Are you doing this in the simulator or on a physical device?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved an error identical to this one. I was incorrectly assuming that the phonegap-1.3.0.js for iPhone was identical to the phonegap-1.3.0.js for Android.

I had a simple tool-chain that was copying the iPhone's phonegap.js file into the Android app, automatically. This effectively disabled all Phone Gap functions.